# Monitor registry using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, monitor

I want to monitor when a key is changed/added/deleted to the registry whenever application is being installed or removed. I have tested the sample code from the msdn([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) and it works fine.

But the problem is that it does not tell me which key has actually been modified/added/deleted. How can i retrieve this information using c++?

Answer (score 7):

There are only 3 ways, none of which is both easy and adequate:

- [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx):
  Doesn't give you the info you need, but is very easy to use.
- [`EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_REGISTRY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364106.aspx) which is part of [Event Tracing for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx)
  which is what [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) uses. It works well, but it's quite difficult to use.
  I'm not sure exactly how to use it myself, but if I figure it out I'll post it here.
- [`CmRegisterCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541918.aspx):
  Requires kernel-mode driver, which is a pain in 64-bit.
  But it's the most perfect solution otherwise.

Comment: Side note: "the **`CmRegisterCallback`** routine is obsolete for Windows Vista and later operating system versions. Use [**`CmRegisterCallbackEx`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541921.aspx) instead."

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Event Tracing for Windows (EWT) does not allow to see full key path in the event. You get only a partial key name and a strange handle with is actually a key control block. It's not so simple to get information from this block. 
Yes the process monitor uses EWT, but it does not use Windows Kernel Trace as a provider.

Comment: See [ETW - Registry monitoring](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff07fc25-31e3-4b6f-810e-7a1ee458084b/etw-registry-monitoring) for how to discover the full key names when using ETW.